# How to query with filter boolean column with 'is' in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When I query this:

```
select * from table_name where active is true
```

the result is

> syntax error: unexpected 'is'.

But when I query

```
select * from table_name where active is not null
```

the result is appear

Data type of the active column is boolean

[image: error result]

Comment: `where active = true` or just `where active`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from values
    (1,true),
    (2,false),
    (3,null)
where column2
```

[image]

or more explicitly:

```
select * from values
    (1,true),
    (2,false),
    (3,null)
where column2 = true
```

the [WHERE clause notes](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/where#usage-notes) talks about `IS` which is used to test the NULL'ness or NOT NULL'ness of the column

thus:

```
select * from values
    (1,true),
    (2,false),
    (3,null)
where column2 IS NULL
```

gives:

[image]

while:

```
select * from values
    (1,true),
    (2,false),
    (3,null)
where column2 IS NOT NULL
```

gives:

[image]